# Adding default attributes of link_to() function in Symfony in routing.yml

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Greets!

I have a question - is it possible to add some attribute (for example, my_attr: my_value) to routing.yml, that will appear every time in `<a>` tag? For example, i'm writing something like ... `link_to('super link', 'super_module')` and when template loads we see `<a href="/path_to_module" my_attr="myvalue">super link</a>` in HTML source code.

Hope, you understood what i want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Nope - this is not part of the route - this is an attribute on the `a` that s produced as a result ...

You could create your own helper or override the link_to function to do what you want

Answer (score 2):

No, the routing classes do not accept any html attribute. That can only be done in the `link_to` function. You can either override the `link_to` and pass the attributes you need or use one array with those attributes as `link_to` parameter.

`link_to` just uses the method `url_for` to generate the link from the routing you give.